# Can you "shrink to fit" clothes?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I once saw someone design a very rough shape for clothes, then run some physics to shrink them into place around the figure. Can Blender do that (run cloth physics while shrinking them)?

Comment: maybe you're talking about cloth sewing? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7h89tkUJLuM

Comment: Thanks, that's close but is there a way to tighten the whole mesh to make it skin tight?

Comment: if you want to create tight clothes maybe use this method, which is basically giving a pin group to most of the cloth except where you want it to be flexible: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbyfuW5Aocg#t=21m35

Comment: Vertex pinning can help.

Comment: Duplicate the part of your character that is supposed to be coverd with cloth. Add a displace modifier, change nothing but the strength to a very low amount.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not optimal, but "Shape" in the Cloth options has a "Shrinking factor", it non-zero it violently shrinks the cloth but it can be animated, so a simulation with this going from zero to whatever desired value will make a skin tight cloth.